# GetCheckedRadioButton worked wrongly in my mfc application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

> Im using some radio buttons in my mfc application . Also i use GetCheckedRadioButton to get the checked radio button . Please refer below code:

```
int id;
id=GetCheckedRadioButton(IDD_RAD1,IDD_RAD11);
```

> if i check in my resource using Alt+E+i , it shows my IDD_RAD1 as 1041 and IDD_RAD11 as 20681. if i check radio button the id value gets correctly for IDD_RAD1 as 1041 but the value gets wrongly for IDD_RAD11 as 20115. i dont know why it gets second radio button id wrongly.Guide me!

Comment: Resource ID values do not get magically assigned. **You** are responsible for assigning them, since only you know the semantics of your UI. If you have the resource editor assign random values, don't complain that it doesn't heed your additional semantic constraints.

Comment: I don't agree to the guy, that downvoted this question. The problem here is the bad and wrong documentation. The name of the function sounds like that it might do a good job. But it doesn't.

Comment: MFC relies on the fact that developers know the Windows API. It does not replicate each and every piece of information. In particular, it does not repeat how control grouping works.

Comment: Since when is GetCheckedRadioButton a Windows API function? How can you know from this name that the IDs must be consecutive? What Windows API function do I need to know? CheckRadioButton? Especially when the DDX functions just relay on WS_GROUP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use this dumb function. GetCheckedRadioButton only works if the IDs are consecutive. And as you wrote they are not.

The documentation is wrong. It doesn't checks the radios in a group!

Better use CWnd::GetNextDlgGroupItem item and use IsDlgButtonChecked on each item.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `resource.h` file, and make the ID consecutive, as in

```
#define IDD_RAD1  1041
#define IDD_RAD11 1042
```

Make sure that all the ID within the same Dialog are unique.

Comment: I never want to relay on code that is based on consecutive ideas. The next programmer might just add a control and knows nothing about the need to IDs in consecutive order... I try to avoid this by using better functions or I try to avoid this by using internal static arrays that map IDs into the sequence I need. Just my 2 cents!

Comment: IDs not ideas :(, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @xMRi Comments are a pretty useful tool, even more so is `C_ASSERT`/`static_assert`. Your proposed workaround to use static arrays is subject to the same problem - it doesn't solve anything. And introduces a new error possibility: Failure to ensure unique IDs.

Comment: The problem isn't about unique IDs. The problem is about having IDs in consecutive sequence. Introducing an array of IDs I get rid of the problem that the change of the ID or the change of the ID sequence will break my code. I don't see that it introduces a new source for errors... and yes, using static_assert and checking if the IDs are consecutive will help. Just my two cents.

Comment: @xMRi however, if there is NO "next programmer", my solution is much simpler :-)

Comment: @manuell: Than it is you. You forget after 3 month that IDs must be in sequence and add a new option. Now you wonder why... I am the kind of programmer who sometimes forget such things... ;)

Comment: @xMRi You are **ignoring** the fact that control ID's sharing the same parent must be unique (on top of being consecutive). Pulling those ID's out of resource.h and constructing a static array in some code module is a collision waiting to happen. Place your checks in whichever code module you like, but leave the ID's in resource.h - that's where they belong.

Comment: You misunderstand what I do. The IDs are still in the resource.h. But the sequence is defined in an UINT[], when I need a sequence... I never relay on IDs in consecutive order. I think we can stop the discussion. We all have our own opinion.

Comment: @xMRi You either mispresent what you are really doing, or you are producing a collision waiting to happen. You have not provided anything that strengthens code quality or safety. I suppose you are in fact merely voicing an **opinion** rather than a verifiably safer solution.

Comment: Again: If I need a special sequence in the controls. I don't relay on Ids. I Place the Ids in an internal array in he dialog source code. So if something changes my resource.h (for example Resource renumber tool), this will never break my code. So code quality rises! Or: As I mentioned, I only use the start ID of a group and use WS_GROUP flags. Again I am secure against changes in the controls, as long as I understand the meaning of the Id ;) OK. And mybe at least: English isn't my native tongue. So may be I can't explain in depth what I really mean. So excuse my humble statement and opinion.